# What is APC AOS cryptlib sshd (protocol 2.0) Service?

Tags: services

While conducting a pentest. I came across a port 22 open. Nmap identified the service as "APC AOS cryptlib sshd (protocol 2.0)" However i am having trouble identified what program is running on this port. From what I can get out google "APC" defines a UPS Device is this correct?

Comment: [This](http://forums.apc.com/spaces/7/ups-management-devices-powerchute-software/forums/general/1785/openssh-v6-7-received-disconnect-handshake-failed) might be of some use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, APC AOS is the firmware running on APC devices, likely to be an UPS.

The service's advertisement – "sshd (protocol 2.0)" – matches the standard assignment of SSH (the Secure Shell protocol) for port 22, a rather common Telnet replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely a Bulletin Board System (a Telnet based BBS) running an SSH port for access. This is very common, and in fact probably the most common reason you would see this fingerprint on a forward facing port on the Internet - especially considering the resurgence in popularity that BBSes have enjoyed over the last few years.

An 'APC UPS' would NOT likely be made available to the Internet as a forward facing device, and typically be kept behind a firewall, or at least, it would not be prudent.

Currently, Synchronet BBS, Mystic BBS, and other BBS systems use this daemon to provide BBS access over SSH. Although you cannot be certain to tell by also scanning for the fingerprint on port 23 (The BBS may be, and often is, made available via telnet on ports other than the standard port assigned by IANA due to the myriad scans on that port), if you do see the Synchronet or Mystic BBS (or another BBS) telnet fingerprint on TCP 23 then that would almost certainly verify that it's also providing services on port 22 via SSH:

```
22/tcp   open     ssh              APC AOS cryptlib sshd (protocol 2.0)
23/tcp   open     telnet           Synchronet BBS 3.17
25/tcp   open     smtp
| fingerprint-strings:
|   GenericLines, GetRequest:
|     220 cvs.synchro.net Synchronet SMTP Server 1.715-Linux Ready
```

and...

```
==============NEXT SERVICE FINGERPRINT (SUBMIT INDIVIDUALLY)==============
SF-Port25-TCP:V=7.70%I=7%D=9/10%Time=5D7883C0%P=x86_64-slackware-linux-gnu
SF:%r(NULL,3E,"220\x20cvs\.synchro\.net\x20Synchronet\x20SMTP\x20Server\x2
SF:01\.715-Linux\x20Ready\r\n")%r(Hello,C8,"220\x20cvs\.synchro\.net\x20Sy
SF:nchronet\x20SMTP\x20Server...
```

or...

```
PORT    STATE  SERVICE    VERSION
22/tcp  open   ssh        APC AOS cryptlib sshd (protocol 2.0)
23/tcp  open   telnet
| fingerprint-strings:
|   GenericLines:
|     [8;25;80t
|     [1;25r
|     [1;1H
|     [1;1H
|     [?1000h
|     Mystic BBS v1.12 A43 for Linux Node 1
|     Copyright (C) 1997-2019 By James Coyle
|     Detecting terminal emulation:
|     [6nASCII detected.
|     Ascii (No Color)
|     Ansi (Color)
|     Graphics Mode ->
|   NULL, tn3270:
|     [8;25;80t
|     [1;25r
|     [1;1H
|     [1;1H
|     [?1000h
|     Mystic BBS v1.12 A43 for Linux Node 1
|     Copyright (C) 1997-2019 By James Coyle
|_    Detecting terminal emulation:
```

Perhaps the easiest way to verify if it's a BBS is just to connect to port 22 with an SSH client and see if the service announces itself as a BBS system. If it is, it will invariably invite you to create a new account and join. There are usually games and message bases available as well once you login and complete a quick registration.